# Can I add a button to launch the selected AVD in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

On the Android Studio toolbar there is a dropdown select list to select which device I want to use and then buttons to do things like run my app on that device or debug my app on that device. If I had selected a virtual device and the device is not currently running, it will automatically start that AVD before taking the requested action.

However, fairly often I need to start the emulator without starting the app - usually because I want to uninstall my app before running it in order to test some "clean install" scenarios, or I want to change something in the device settings before running the app. At the moment I usually do this by just going to the device manager, finding the relevant virtual device in the list and starting it from there. But this is a bit cumbersome, and I'm wondering if there's a way to add a button in the Android Studio toolbar to enable me to just start the selected device without actually running my app? I know there are lots of things you can add to the toolbar, including custom macros, so I'm not sure if there's a way to do this.